# How to add prefix for each new line in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, reactjs

I am working on a react project. I have a string that may contain newlines in it. How do I inject a symbol at the start o each line? What would be the most efficient way? (I am thinking of exploding the string into an array and adding a chat at the start of each line but that seems like a really inefficient way of doing things)

Change this

```
var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Vestibulum pellentesque";
```

into

```
var text = "> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
> consectetur adipiscing elit. 
> Vestibulum pellentesque"
```

How to add a symbol after each instance of "\n"?

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary**_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do this `str.replace('\n', '\n>');`. And then find a way to add it to the first line. simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can use **tagged template literals** (ES6)...

### Verbose version with `for...of`

```js
function addPrefix(str) {
  let tmp = str[0].split('\n'),
      res = [];
      
  for (const frag of tmp) {
    res.push(`> ${frag}`);
  }
  
  return res.join('\n');
}

let str = addPrefix`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Vestibulum pellentesque`;

console.log(str);
```

### One-liner with `Array.prototype.map()` (see [Miguel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3276721/miguel-lattuada)'s comment)

```js
const addPrefix = str => str[0].split('\n').map(s => `> ${s}`).join('\n');

let str = addPrefix`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Vestibulum pellentesque`;

console.log(str);
```

Comment: str.split('\n').map(s => `> ${s}`).join('\n');

Comment: Nice suggestion for one-liners fans. I admit my solution is a bit verbose... :)

Comment: I am not surprised. One-liners are cool and powerful, but they are much harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

To insert something at the beginning of each line of a string, use `replace` with the regular expression `/^/gm`, i.e. `str.replace(/^/gm, prefix)`:

```js
const Formatter = ({text, prefix}) => (
  <textarea>{text.replace(/^/gm, prefix)}</textarea>
);

const text = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Vestibulum pellentesque`;

const prefix = '> ';

ReactDOM.render(<Formatter text={text} prefix={prefix}/>, document.querySelector('div'));
```

```css
textarea { font-family: monospace; width: 100%; height: 4em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```